# Mail.app @hotmail.com Exchange

Tags: mail.app, email, macos, imap

Is it possible (in any way!) to enable my @live.nl, @outlook.com, @hotmail.com accounts through Exchange, into the stock Mail application? I'm willing to buy Office 365 for one account (and remove the others) as long as it supports 'offline' push messages. I've tried the following:

> Add the account through 'Internet accounts' in System Preferences. As the exchange server, I've tried: m.outlook.com and s.outlook.com.

From what I've read, OS X Mail.app does not support EAS (Exchange Active Sync), which is the only form of Exchange supported by @outlook.com, @live.nl, @hotmail.com etc. Could anyone verify this?

EDIT:
For clarification, I want to have an Exchange set-up to receive the additional contact, calendar and reminders syncing.

Comment: You are correct that, as of November 2014, Apple Mail does not support Exchange ActiveSync. To get what you want, either Microsoft has to add in Exchange Web Services support to Outlook.com/live.com (which Apple Mail already supports), or Apple has to license and implement EAS into Apple Mail.

Comment: Thank you @nadyne . Any solutions that you might suggest?

Comment: If you want an Exchange account, then you will have to pay for one.  One option is to get one directly from Microsoft, which is available either standalone or as an add-on to Office 365. http://products.office.com/en-us/exchange/compare-microsoft-exchange-online-plans
There are also hosted Exchange providers.  All of my Exchange accounts have been provided by the IT department of my various employers, so I don't have a particular recommendation.

Comment: So if I were to get 'Exchange Online Plan 1' from the link you delivered in the post above. I would be able to get all the benefits of Exchange (e.g. contact, calendar and reminder sync) on Mac OS X (Yosemite)? @nadyne

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  It's probably worth verifying with someone who's actually purchased that plan, which I have not.

Answer (score 1):

To add Microsoft mail accounts to mail, you have to select 'Add other account...' from the internet accounts list. Then enter your hotmail email and password as normal.

[image: Internet Accounts]

Comment: I am aware of this. I am able to add x@outlook.com, x@live.nl and x@hotmail.com accounts as IMAP. What I am trying to achieve is adding them under Exchange, so I get the additional contact, calendar and reminders sync.

Comment: There wasn't a way afaik. I tried this in the past and had no success.

Answer (score -3):

If you really want to go through all these expenses,why not load "Windows Parallel" and load "windows ,along with Microsoft outlook".

Comment: What is  "Windows Parallel"  ?

Comment: You're absolutely right. The fact that I don't want this solution is that Windows ISO takes up more than 20GB and I only have a 120GB SSD. @Mark, Zaza is talking about Parallels (virtualization software).